# Neighborhoods are open proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

[image]

Let $r' = r - a$

I am trying to proof that neighbourhoods or open balls is an open set. I've watched this video 
on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zs_PTUfKAk&list=PL0E754696F72137EC&index=10&feature=plpp_video) where the guy explains how the triangle inequality comes into play. I quote

> Anything that's distance less than r' from q is going to be distance
>   less than r from p

Can someone show me how that is done? All I can write is that for some x that's between the q and r', and p and r. I get  $|x - q| < r' < |x - p| < r$

Comment: jak, do you mean to say let $r^\prime = r-a$?

Comment: @amWhy, yes I did... let me fix that

Comment: «Neighborhood» and «open ball» do not mean the same thing.

Comment: I thought they do mean the same thing. I am reading a book by Rudin and it seems like that's what they are implying with the "radius" of the neighborhood. He even mentioned an example that in $\mathbb{R^2}$, the neighbourhoods are the interiors of the circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r'=r-a$. Suppose that $|x-q|<r'$. Then $$|x-p|\le|x-q|+|q-p|<r'+a=(r-a)+a=r\;,$$

and you’re done. The first step is the triangle inequality, the next is the assumption that $|x-q|<r'$ together with the fact that $|q-p|=a$, and the rest is just algebra.